# Typemock Isolator: How to mock a DbContext that is not injected?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, dependency-injection, typemock-isolator

I'm testing my repositories in a Asp.Net MVC project and I need to mock a DbContext for my Unit Tests. DbContext is not injected and I can't change the code.

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978273/typemock-isolator-mock-a-dependency-thats-not-injected) out and I followed it step by step but it didn't work. This is my code, I tried to simplify it:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveAmountsAfterCalculation()
    {
        // Faking the Context
        var fakeContext = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<MyContext>();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => new MyContext()).WillReturn(fakeContext);

        // Faking one the the DbSetList of the Context
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeContext.SomeDbSet)
        .WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(somehtingElseList);

        // Calling the method to test
        MyRepository.SaveAmountsAfterCalculation();

        // Verifying if SomeProperty was called
        Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(() => fakeContext
        .SomeProperty.Attach(null));
    }
```

When the context is created within using statement, no exception is thrown.

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
   ...
   // The exception is thrown here.
   if (ctx.SomeDbSet.Any(...))
   ...
}
```

but if I inspect any property (DbSet) then I can see this error: **No connection string named 'MyContext' could be found in the application config file.**. I already added a connection string to my Test project, but it didn't work either. The moment that `SomeDbSet`is called, then the Exception is thrown even when I told TypeMock to replace the result of that method with `somethingElse`. See the code above.

Comment: Luis can you post your full test and the method under test? its difficult to understand what is the problem without it.

Comment: it is done @JamesR!

Comment: your example is not so clear, first you didn't supply your tested method implementation(**SaveAmountsAfterCalculation**) so it hard to understand what you are testing, second the property **SomeProperty** you are trying to verify is also not shown. please give a more detailed example so we can try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line `"Isolate.WhenCalled(() => new MyContext()).WillReturn(fakeContext);`" is obsolete and perhaps causing your problem because you already faked the call  **`"new MyContext()"`** when you used **fakeNextInstance**.

Comment: what is the **somehtingElse** instance?

Comment: This is a list of something. I did not use my real names for simplicity.